# Why this includes() case return false?

Tags: javascript

```js
var product_id = "14728";
console.log(product_id.includes("14782,12434,3143")); // this return false
```

[Example](https://alligator.io/js/includes-string-method/).

I just want to check that my **product_id** is within those other articles ids string

Comment: Use ```var product_id = "14782";
console.log("14782,12434,3143".includes(product_id));```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. You have it backwards. You are asking if `"14728"` includes `"14782,12434,3143"` (which it doesn't, the latter is too long to be included in the former for a start), not the other way around
2. `"14782,12434,3143"` **doesn't** include `"14728"` anyway

Your approach is also broken. `"14782,12434,3143"` includes `"314"`. Presumably you want to only match complete numbers in the comma-separated list. You need to use `Array.prototype.includes`, not `String.prototype.includes`.

```js
const myData = ["14782", "12434", "3143"];

const mySearch = "14728";      // Not in the array
const myOtherSearch = "12434"; // In the array

console.log(myData.includes(mySearch));
console.log(myData.includes(myOtherSearch));
```